# Phrase querying python

Tags: python, search

say we had a phrase such as "natural sciences" and we had file which stored something like this. `'natural'['0','1'['222']] <-` this meaning natural is in document 0, once at position 222.

How would I create a query that checked whether sciences came immediately after?
so for example `'sciences'['0','1'['223']] <-`

Can't quite get my head round the algorithm

so this is the format `'61': ['0:4[106, 223, 339, 775]', '1:3[103, 220, 336]']` so 61 refers to a word in another table, 0 is the document its from, 4 is the amount of times it appears in that document, it then repeats so it is in document 1 3 times

Comment: wouldn't `sciences` also be in quotes like `natural`?

Comment: @RNar yeah sure, sorry my mistake

Comment: If you read in `['0', '1', ['222']]`, can you figure out how to construct ``['0', '1', ['223']]`? (But why are all these numbers stored as strings? I'd start by turning them into numbers as they're read in.)

Comment: Is your starting point the original document, or this encoded version of word positions? What do you want to retrieve at the end? the position, the count, or what?

Comment: so this is the format `'61': ['0:4[106, 223, 339, 775]', '1:3[103, 220, 336]']` so 61 refers to a word in another table, 0 is the document its from, 4 is the amount of times it appears in that document, it then repeats so it is in document 1 3 times @alexis

Comment: encoded versions of word positions, I want to retrieve where the words are next to each other in a specific document, and thus return that document.. or series of documents @beroe

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an index of word occurrences. The natural thing to do is to load this index in a form that you can use easily: As a dictionary of words, where each word is associated with an index of its occurrences. For the kind of query you describe I'd keep it simple: The index for each word is a **set** of tuples in the form `(fileid, position)`. E.g., your example becomes `("0", 106), ("0", 223), ...`. This is ideal for your multi-word query, but is less efficient for answering the question "does word W occur in file X".

This is your sample data:

```
'61': ['0:4[106, 223, 339, 775]', '1:3[103, 220, 336]']
```

1. The master index can be a dictionary, but for convenience I'll make it a `defaultdict(set)`:

   ```
   from collections import defaultdict
   master_index = defaultdict(set)
   ```
2. Read in the table that shows you what word is meant by `61`, and use it to convert these indices to words as soon as you read a record. E.g.,

   ```
   word = mainwords[61]
   ```
3. Read each record of word occurrences, and build the index for this word:

   ```
   master_index[word].add(("0", n) for n in [106, 223, 339, 775])
   master_index[word].add(("1", n) for n in [103, 220, 336])
   ```

I'll leave it to you to do the parsing and type conversions. Note that you can discard the number of occurrences per file.

Once you have your index, your query is pretty simple:

```
positionsafter = set((fid, n+1) for fid, n in master_index["natural"])
hits = master_index["selection"] & positionsafter
for fileid, pos in sorted(hits):
    print(fileid, pos-1, pos)
```

We made a set of all positions that *follow* an occurrence of "natural", and used set intersection `&` to find which of them, if any, are among the positions of "selection".